# Debian: Microsoft team restart/crush while screen sharing

Tags: microsoft-teams, debian-buster

I installed latest Microsoft team in debian 10 buster. I tried to share my desktop with my group but Microsoft team restarts automatically every time. I tried instructions provided [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-crashes-my-pc-on-screen-share/2dadec3f-94ae-46cc-9274-ef9b260828e1) e.g reinstalling, logout, clear cash etc. But, It doesn't help. What next should I try?

Comment: Please use "Report a problem" option under Help menu to report this problem directly to the right team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, you will see a black screen while desktop/screen sharing. Anyway, lets try out this. Login as a root user then go to etc/gdm3 and find daemon.conf file. Open it and find the following line.

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Uncomment/remove the hash before WaylandEnable

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Finally, reboot your system.

Comment: I forgot to mention about black screen. OMG. it works like a champ. Thanks